# Is there something wrong with this definition of ordered pair?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've come across the definition of ordered pair as (a,b)={a,{a,b}}. How I think it works is by providing enough information to differentiate the order of the elements in the pair. I thought an alternate way of defining it is as follows:
(a,b)={a,{b}}.
Is there something wrong with this definition?

Comment: Yes, there is, it yields ({1},0) = ({0},1) for example

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: The usual definition is $\{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$. The definition you’ve come across, $\{a,\{a,b\}\},$ works but requires the axiom of foundation.